# listen to model events in view

Tags: backbone.js

I try to render view when model changes.
Could you please tell why this code doens't wok?

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },
});
```

It gives error:

```
TypeError: this.model.on is not a function
```

But it looks like this code works:

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');  
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);  
    },
});
```

These libraries are used:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more details and especially to clarify "doesn't work". Be specific. Provide error messages or what you do, what you expect to happen, and what happens or doesn't happen instead. Both of those isolated snippets look fine to me. The problem is likely in other code you haven't included.

Comment: I edited post. Error says: "TypeError: this.model.on is not a function"

Comment: I take it that the ancient and out of date blog post that uses 0.3.3 is still near the top of Google's "backbone tutorial" results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `on` and `off` methods were added to Backbone in version `0.9.0`, and it looks like you are still version `0.3.3`. You can continue to use `bind` and `unbind`. The new `on`/`off` methods are just aliases for the same thing.

Alternatively you should consider updating your Backbone version. Since `0.3.3` there have been hundreds of other improvements and bugfixes to Backbone, so you should update to the newest (`0.9.10`) if you're able. At the same time you need to update underscore to version  `>= 1.4.3`